Reference for uniqueness of vector realizations of a Gram matrix
Let $v_i,\ldots,v_n\in\mathbb R^k$, and let $G_{ij} = \langle v_i, v_j\rangle$ be their Gram matrix.
As Wikipedia notes, the Gram matrix $G$ uniquely specified the geometry of the $v_i$: if there is a separate set of vectors $u_i\in\mathbb R^k$ such that $G_{ij} = \langle u_i, u_j\rangle$, then the two sets are related by an isometry, $u_i = Rv_i$ with $R\in \mathrm{O}(k)$.
Wikipedia's reference (Theorem 7.3.11 in Horn & Johnson) is OK, but it's not very specific to Gram matrices, and I'd like to find a reference which is short, clean, and specific to that context. Does anybody have one handy?
(So, for clarity: explicit proofs given here are not particularly useful; I want something that I can cite, in a physics paper, and that will quickly and efficiently prove the result and explain to a physics audience why it is true.)

I have devised a proof that covers also the case where $G$ is singular.

(For the proof itself, this question contains multiple examples.)
